# Listview not displaying in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Listview is not displaying in fragment in tablayout and i am getting data from firebase realtime database.

I have tried using listfragment but it did not work.

```
public class AdminManagerListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView managersList;
    private ArrayList<String> managers;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public AdminManagerListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_manager_list, container, false);
        managers = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfManagers();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, managers);
        managersList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        managersList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }


    private void listOfManagers() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String value = (String) dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue();
                if (value.equals("manager")) {
                    String username = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
                    managers.add(username);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to display listview in fragment which contains data downloaded from firebase.

Comment: Did you check that the condition `if (value.equals("manager"))` is actually `true`? Because the ListView and the Adapter look to be fine.

Comment: Is your `onChildAdded` ever called? For example: if you put a breakpoint on the first line inside that method, and run it in a debugger, does the breakpoint ever get hit?

Comment: also to mention now i have updated my code to use recyclerview instead of listview but its still not working?

Comment: Since you commented on my answer that your `onChildAdded` gets called, let's continue debugging here. The next step would be to put a breakpoint in `onChildAdded` and step through the code. Does the breakpoint get hit? When step further after that, does it go into the `if` statement? Does it get the right `username`? Stack Overflow is a horrible inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you do many of those steps in one go on your own.

Comment: I dont understand as even if i comment out the firebase method and just try to create a simple arraylist with hard coded values then also list is not displayed

Comment: OK. That means the problem is not related to Firebase, and I'm not really the best person to help. I hope somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Have you added any chield after run the application while your app is foreground.After run the application add chield to firebase

Comment: once try adding static data rather than calling firebase database and check once is it working fine?

Comment: add the data before set the adapter

Comment: i commented out listOfManagers() method and in place of this i entered hard coded value but then also the listview is not getting displayed also i tried recyclerview and updated my whole code but still i cannot find any recyclerview in fragment.

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to help, looks like the error was with my xml code the list was hiding under the tooldbar and tabs which i corrected by adding a linear layout around my toolbar and viewpager.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer to the problem you're having, but it's a useful change to the code that is too long to fit in a comment.*

Your current code is loading all data from the database, and then locally filters for the correct data. It's more efficient to let the database do that filtering by  using a query. The equivalent filtering is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
  .orderByChild("userType").equalToValue("manager")
  .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        String username = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
        managers.add(username);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: But what about the answer pls help

Comment: I left a comment on your question too, with some questions that we need to be able to help. Please respond there, instead of an off-topic response here.

Comment: yes onChildAdded is called and i have a user in my firebase database which has a userType manager